# Joining two datasets from separate seasons/years, sports related (e.g., NHL, 1991 & 1992 seasons)

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, dataset

I have data sets for NHL teams, over a certain number of years. I want to know the best way to join these data sets. For example, I have Chicago Blackhawks stats from 1991 and 1992, with Games Played (GP), Wins (W), Losses (L), etc.

How would I join these sets together, without creating two separate columns, GP.x and GP.y?

I've used **dput()** to get the first ten teams and their respective statistics:

---

```
# 1991 team stats - first ten teams

structure(list(Team = c("Chicago Blackhawks*", "St. Louis Blues*", 
   "Los Angeles Kings*", "Boston Bruins*", "Calgary Flames*", 
   "Montreal Canadiens*", "Pittsburgh Penguins*", "New York Rangers*", 
   "Washington Capitals*", "Buffalo Sabres*"), 
GP = c("80", "80", "80", "80", "80", "80", "80", "80", "80", "80"), 
W = c("49", "47", "46", "44", "46", "39", "41", "36", "37", "31"), 
L = c("23", "22", "24", "24", "26", "30", "33", "31", "36", "30"), 
T = c("8", "11", "10", "12", "8", "11", "6", "13", "7", "19"), 
Pts = c("106", "105", "102", "100", "100", "89", "88", "85", "81","81"), 
`Pts %` = c(".663", ".656", ".638", ".625", ".625", ".556", ".550", 
   ".531", ".506", ".506"), 
GF = c("284", "310", "340", "299", "344", "273", "342", "297", "258", 
   "292"), 
GA = c("211", "250", "254", "264", "263", "249", "305", "265", "258", 
   "278"), 
SRS = c("0.85", "0.70", "1.04", 
   "0.32", "0.98", "0.20", "0.42", "0.36", "0.00", "0.08"), 
SOS = c("-0.06", "-0.05", "-0.04", "-0.12", "-0.03", "-0.10", "-0.04", 
   "-0.04", "0.00", "-0.09"), 
`TG/G` = c("6.19", "7.00", "7.43", "7.04", "7.59", "6.53", "8.09", 
   "7.03", "6.45", "7.13"), 
EVGF = c("177", "230", "252", "214", "236", "201", "241", "197", "181", 
   "204"), 
EVGA = c("132", "177", "173", "192", "178", "185", "220", "182", "199", 
   "208"), 
PP = c("87", "70", "80", "74", "91", "66", "89", "91", "64", "73"), 
PPO = c("393", "348", "391", "351", "384", "357", "388", "389", "340", 
   "400"), 
`PP%` = c("22.14", "20.11", "20.46", "21.08", "23.70", "18.49", "22.94", 
   "23.39", "18.82", "18.25"), 
PPA = c("68", "55", "63", "64", "77", "54", "73", "73", "44", "62"), 
PPOA = c("425", "339", "370", "368", "420", "282", "351", "362", "314", 
   "368"), 
`PK%` = c("84.00", "83.78", "82.97", "82.61", "81.67", "80.85", "79.20", 
   "79.83", "85.99", "83.15"), 
SH = c("20", "10", "8", "11", "17", "6", "12", "9", "13", "15"), 
SHA = c("10", "18", "18", "8", "8", "10", "12", "10", "15", "8"), 
`PIM/G` = c("29.9", "24.6", "27.6", "20.8", "27.1", "17.6", "20.4", 
   "23.4", "22.8", "21.3"), 
`oPIM/G` = c("28.2", "25.3", "30.5", "23.3", "25.9", "19.5", "21.3", 
   "24.1", "25.3", "22.1"), 
S = c("2564", "2550", "2410", "2512", "2604", "2385", "2416", "2444", 
   "2370", "2410"), 
`S%` = c("11.1", "12.2", "14.1", "11.9", "13.2", "11.4", "14.2", "12.2", 
   "10.9", "12.1"), 
SA = c("2214", "2345", "2412", "2240", "2200", "2316", "2723", "2550", 
   "2112", "2432"), 
`SV%` = c(".905", ".893", ".895", ".882", ".880", ".892", 
   ".888", ".896", ".878", ".886"),
PDO = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), 
.Names = c("Team", "GP", "W", "L", "T", "Pts", "Pts %", "GF", "GA", 
   "SRS", "SOS", "TG/G", "EVGF", "EVGA", "PP", "PPO", "PP%", "PPA", 
   "PPOA", "PK%", "SH", "SHA", "PIM/G", "oPIM/G", "S", "S%", "SA", 
   "SV%", "PDO"), 
row.names = 2:11, class = "data.frame")
```

---

```
# 1992 team stats - first ten teams

structure(list(Team = c("New York Rangers*", "Washington Capitals*", 
   "Detroit Red Wings*", "Vancouver Canucks*", "Montreal Canadiens*", 
   "Pittsburgh Penguins*", "Chicago Blackhawks*", "New Jersey Devils*", 
   "Boston Bruins*", "Los Angeles Kings*"), 
GP = c("80", "80", "80", 
   "80", "80", "80", "80", "80", "80", "80"),
W = c("50", "45", "43", "42", "41", "39", "36", "38", "36", "35"),
L = c("25", "27", "25", "26", "28", "32", "29", "31", "32", "31"), 
T = c("5", "8", "12", "12", "11", "9", "15", "11", "12", "14"), 
Pts = c("105", "98", "98", "96", "93", "87", "87", "87", "84", "84"), 
`Pts %` = c(".656", ".613", ".613", ".600", ".581", ".544", ".544", 
   ".544", ".525", ".525"), 
GF = c("321", "330", "320", "285", "267", "343", "257", "289", "270", 
   "287"), 
GA = c("246", "275", "256", "250", 
   "207", "308", "236", "259", "275", "296"), 
SRS = c("1.02", "0.78", "0.74", "0.31", "0.64", "0.52", "0.22", "0.48", 
   "-0.09", "-0.19"), 
SOS = c("0.08", "0.09", "-0.06", "-0.13", "-0.12", "0.08", "-0.04", 
   "0.10", "-0.03", "-0.08"), 
`TG/G` = c("7.09", "7.56", "7.20", "6.69", "5.93", "8.14", "6.16", 
   "6.85", "6.81", "7.29"), 
EVGF = c("226", "224", "230", "188", "189", "235", "165", "215", "186", 
   "197"), 
EVGA = c("174", "200", "171", "167", "142", "217", "150", "181", "189", 
   "208"), 
PP = c("81", "92", "72", "85", "74", "92", "81", "59", "77", "79"), 
PPO = c("387", "412", "386", "439", "379", "423", "467", "338", "406", 
   "411"), 
`PP%` = c("20.93", "22.33", "18.65", "19.36", "19.53", "21.75", "17.34", 
   "17.46", "18.97", "19.22"), 
PPA = c("60", "60", "78", "76", "60", "77", "76", "68", "72", "76"), 
PPOA = c("395", "368", "419", "382", "320", "383", "482", "374", "363", 
   "417"), 
`PK%` = c("84.81", "83.70", "81.38", "80.10", "81.25", "79.90", 
   "84.23", "81.82", "80.17", "81.77"), 
SH = c("14", "14", "18", 
   "12", "4", "16", "11", "15", "7", "11"), 
SHA = c("12", "15", 
   "7", "7", "5", "14", "10", "10", "14", "12"), 
`PIM/G` = c("22.4", "21.8", "25.6", "25.7", "19.3", "23.7", "33.0", 
   "20.0", "21.8", "26.9"), 
`oPIM/G` = c("24.1", "24.2", "23.9", "28.4", "22.0", 
   "23.9", "31.8", "20.4", "23.7", "25.6"), 
S = c("2632", "2481", "2478", "2669", "2443", "2542", "2646", "2495", 
   "2664", "2419"), 
`S%` = c("12.2", "13.3", "12.9", "10.7", "10.9", "13.5", "9.7", 
   "11.6", "10.1", "11.9"), 
SA = c("2543", "2270", "2238", "2299", "2227", "2518", "2028", "2290", 
   "2339", "2663"), 
`SV%` = c(".903", ".879", ".886", ".891", ".907", ".878", ".884", 
   ".887", ".882", ".889"), 
PDO = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), 
.Names = c("Team", "GP", "W", "L", "T", "Pts", "Pts %", "GF", "GA", 
   "SRS", "SOS", "TG/G", "EVGF", "EVGA", "PP", "PPO", "PP%", "PPA", 
   "PPOA", "PK%", "SH", "SHA", "PIM/G", "oPIM/G", "S", "S%", "SA", 
   "SV%", "PDO"), 
row.names = 2:11, class = "data.frame")
```

---

I understand joining these sets may be... tough, but any advice/thoughts would be great! Thanks!

Comment: I don't think joining will be tough but we need look at data in order to understand relationship. Can you please add part of `team_stats_1991` and `team_stats_1992` data frmaes. You can add output of `dput(head(team_stats_1992, 10))` and ``dput(head(team_stats_1991, 10))` as part of question.

Comment: If the issue isn't really with using RSelenium, only a data wrangling question, please edit the post to only have the requisite information. `dput` the data frames you're trying to join so we have access to those without having to do all the RSelenium stuff to get the data

Comment: @camille - also correct? Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Do you want to just add a year column to each data frame, and then bind the rows together? That would be easiest and probably most flexible

Comment: @camille I am a complete nincompoop - thanks. That works. If you want to add your answer below, I'll confirm that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that trying to merge, join, or `cbind` two data frames with the same column names will either give you column names like `GP.x`, which you said you don't want, or will throw errors when you try to create multiple columns with the same name. You can verify that the two data frames have identical column names like so:

```r
names(df91) == names(df92)
#>  [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [15] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [29] TRUE
```

It also is just more logical to have, for example, all your GP observations under a single column `GP` where observations are demarcated with the year in which they occurred, rather than two `GP` columns and no clear way of knowing which is for which year. This also wouldn't scale well—if you're scraping score data, I'm guessing at some point you'll want more than just these two years.

You instead want to be binding rows. You can give each data frame a column for the year, and use `rbind` in base R to bind them into one data frame.

```r
df91$year <- 1991
df92$year <- 1992

df_base <- rbind(df91, df92)
head(df_base)
#>                  Team GP  W  L  T Pts Pts %  GF  GA  SRS   SOS TG/G EVGF
#> 2 Chicago Blackhawks* 80 49 23  8 106  .663 284 211 0.85 -0.06 6.19  177
#> 3    St. Louis Blues* 80 47 22 11 105  .656 310 250 0.70 -0.05 7.00  230
#> 4  Los Angeles Kings* 80 46 24 10 102  .638 340 254 1.04 -0.04 7.43  252
#> 5      Boston Bruins* 80 44 24 12 100  .625 299 264 0.32 -0.12 7.04  214
#> 6     Calgary Flames* 80 46 26  8 100  .625 344 263 0.98 -0.03 7.59  236
#> 7 Montreal Canadiens* 80 39 30 11  89  .556 273 249 0.20 -0.10 6.53  201
#>   EVGA PP PPO   PP% PPA PPOA   PK% SH SHA PIM/G oPIM/G    S   S%   SA  SV%
#> 2  132 87 393 22.14  68  425 84.00 20  10  29.9   28.2 2564 11.1 2214 .905
#> 3  177 70 348 20.11  55  339 83.78 10  18  24.6   25.3 2550 12.2 2345 .893
#> 4  173 80 391 20.46  63  370 82.97  8  18  27.6   30.5 2410 14.1 2412 .895
#> 5  192 74 351 21.08  64  368 82.61 11   8  20.8   23.3 2512 11.9 2240 .882
#> 6  178 91 384 23.70  77  420 81.67 17   8  27.1   25.9 2604 13.2 2200 .880
#> 7  185 66 357 18.49  54  282 80.85  6  10  17.6   19.5 2385 11.4 2316 .892
#>   PDO year
#> 2     1991
#> 3     1991
#> 4     1991
#> 5     1991
#> 6     1991
#> 7     1991
```

Or you can do it in one step with `dplyr`'s `bind_rows`, and `mutate` to create the year columns. `bind_rows` has the advantage also of not being limited to 2 arguments, so you can scale this if you have more than just these two years' worth of data.

```r
df_dplyr <- dplyr::bind_rows(
  dplyr::mutate(df91, year = 1991),
  dplyr::mutate(df92, year = 1992)
)
head(df_dplyr)
#>                  Team GP  W  L  T Pts Pts %  GF  GA  SRS   SOS TG/G EVGF
#> 1 Chicago Blackhawks* 80 49 23  8 106  .663 284 211 0.85 -0.06 6.19  177
#> 2    St. Louis Blues* 80 47 22 11 105  .656 310 250 0.70 -0.05 7.00  230
#> 3  Los Angeles Kings* 80 46 24 10 102  .638 340 254 1.04 -0.04 7.43  252
#> 4      Boston Bruins* 80 44 24 12 100  .625 299 264 0.32 -0.12 7.04  214
#> 5     Calgary Flames* 80 46 26  8 100  .625 344 263 0.98 -0.03 7.59  236
#> 6 Montreal Canadiens* 80 39 30 11  89  .556 273 249 0.20 -0.10 6.53  201
#>   EVGA PP PPO   PP% PPA PPOA   PK% SH SHA PIM/G oPIM/G    S   S%   SA  SV%
#> 1  132 87 393 22.14  68  425 84.00 20  10  29.9   28.2 2564 11.1 2214 .905
#> 2  177 70 348 20.11  55  339 83.78 10  18  24.6   25.3 2550 12.2 2345 .893
#> 3  173 80 391 20.46  63  370 82.97  8  18  27.6   30.5 2410 14.1 2412 .895
#> 4  192 74 351 21.08  64  368 82.61 11   8  20.8   23.3 2512 11.9 2240 .882
#> 5  178 91 384 23.70  77  420 81.67 17   8  27.1   25.9 2604 13.2 2200 .880
#> 6  185 66 357 18.49  54  282 80.85  6  10  17.6   19.5 2385 11.4 2316 .892
#>   PDO year
#> 1     1991
#> 2     1991
#> 3     1991
#> 4     1991
#> 5     1991
#> 6     1991
```

Created on 2018-06-18 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).